# How to arrive at the answer $x_k= a^{-\frac{1}{p}}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, lp-spaces

[image]

My question is: How to arrive at the answer $x_k = a^{-\frac{1}{p}}$?
I differentiated the expression Lagrangian that  the author has defined w.r.t lambda and equated it to zero giving me summation over k from 1 to a ${}$|| xk|| equal to 1.which is giving me back the constraint.
 I don't know how to proceed futher in obtaining the solution $x_k = a^{-\frac{1}{p}}$.I don't know LaTeX.

Comment: i diffrenentiated the expression lagrangian that  the author has defined w.r.t lambda and equated it to zero giving me summation over k from 1 to a || xk|| equal to 1.

Comment: I would suggest to include your attempts (possibly in LaTeX) in the question, so that people can see what you have done and what exactly you don't understand and be more willing to help you.

Comment: i diffrenentiated the expression lagrangian that  the author has defined w.r.t lambda and equated it to zero giving me summation over k from 1 to a || xk|| equal to 1.which is giving me back the constraint.i dont know how to proceed futher in obtaining the solution x subscript k =a^(-1/p).i dont know latex,madam.